# How to boot linux from an external hard drive?

Tags: unix, dual-boot

I am looking into booting the latest Ubuntu distro (14.04) from an external hard drive using my Macbook Air mid 2012 running Mavericks. I've looked around and couldn't find a link to any step-by-step or instructional page to help me do this (or if its even possible).

Comment: Could you link to the article you found that best showed what you wanted to do? What version of linux? What distribution? We can help you with specifics, but this could really be wide open without some details.

Comment: I want the latest Ubuntu distro (14.04 i thi

Comment: consider this https://scottlinux.com/2010/06/26/mac-how-to-install-ubuntu-to-external-usb-hard-drive/

Answer (score 1):

That looks interesting but I am wondering why they tell you to boot from the 3rd party boot CD.

Once you have a bootable drive wouldn't just pressing OPTION at boot allow you to select the external Ubuntu USB drive? Or am I missing something here?